# In React.js, Wrong clientHeight Got When Use flexGrow

Tags: reactjs, css, flexbox

I was creating a image container that can auto fit the every line and keep the scale ratio, so I use the flex ,after set the width and flexGrow, everything looks just fine

[Demo Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/82p4ov69r0)

But when I try to get the size of the child item, the result clientHeight is not Right.

You can see the output of the browser.

(and the codesandbox demo does not behave the same in chrome when use local build: 
after reload the value suddenly be close to the right value in the codesandbox.)

So, what's going on? Am I missing something,or the code is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN - Element.clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)

> The Element.clientHeight read-only property is zero for elements with no CSS or inline layout boxes, otherwise it's the inner height of an element in pixels, including padding but not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or **margin.**

Emphasis mine.

Your code sandbox output for me:

```
1 
True Height 
233.8
Wrong Height 
239
clientWidth 
167
```

In case you are wondering about the decimal point difference, the link also notes:

> Note: This property will round the value to an integer. If you need a fractional value, use element.getBoundingClientRect().

---

Actually, the problem here is different than what I initially thought.
[Working Codepen Fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/8kyjqvw128)

The problem with your code initially was that you were attempting to check for the height before the component is actually rendered to the DOM.

Since the height of the div depends on the size of the window - when the window is resized, you will need to re-calculate it.

To do this, I added a window resize listener:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateHeightHandler);
  }
```

I also added a Handler - called every time the window is resized - which sets the state on window resize, and then logs the output to the console:

```
updateHeightHandler = () => {
  console.log("UPDATE HEIGHT HANDLER");
  this.setState({
    div1Height: this.div1.clientHeight,
    div2Height: this.div2.clientHeight,
    div3Height: this.div3.clientHeight
  });
  this.logHeightHandler();
};
```

I initially tried to get this working without the on window resize handler (with the setstate logic directly in componentDidMount) and it was not working. The images were not loaded by the time componentDidMount() was fired, thus leading to incorrect results. Once I realized what the problem was, the solution to check it on resize made sense to me, but I am open to alternative suggestions as how this could be accomplished!

---

If it is a requirement to get the height immediately after the images loads, and not after the window is resized - you can add on onLoad event to the `<img>` element, like so:

```
onLoad={this.onImageLoadHandler}
```

From there, you would simply set the state for the div corresponding to the image that is loaded.

If you need additional clarification on how to implement that, let me know and I can update the codepen.

Comment: I don't know what's going on here,but my browser's output is ` Wrong Height 18
`

Comment: wow,that's it,I just forgot the `onLoad`. You really helped me!